# NewMailEx Event is not firing in MS Outlook 2003

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-2003

I am trying to read the body of new mail that is coming in Outlook 2003. For this I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll(11.0.0.0). Below is the code I am using, for triggering the **NewMailEx** event

```
// Create an Outlook application object. 
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application outLookApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();

// Ring up the new message event.
outLookApp.NewMailEx += new ApplicationEvents_11_NewMailExEventHandler(outLookApp_NewMailEx);
```

But this code is not firing the event whenever new mail is coming.
I am using Visual Studio 2010,MS Outlook 2003 and Windows XP professional operating system.

But when I am running same code in MS Outlook 2010 in Windows 7, its working fine. 
What might be the possible reason of not firing **NewMailEx** event in MS Outlook 2003?

Answer (score 0):

Is outLookApp declared as a local variable (which will be garbage collected almost immediately) or as a global/class variable that stays alive for the lifetime of your app?